# Waiting for a script to finish (C#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am developing a game. In the game i have to wait for some scripts to put them in order.
Currently my code is below and it works great.

```
IEnumerator _Something = null;
IEnumerator Something()
{
    yield return null;
    //do something

    _Something = null;
}
IEnumerator TriggerSomething()
{
    while (_Something != null) { yield return null; }
    _Something = Something(); StartCoroutine(_Something);
}
```

The problem is game performance. This code causes low performance in the game.
Is there any way to wait for a script to finish it's task and then the other starts new task in same void method?
Thanks

Comment: if you encounter bad performance, you should consider to use a profiling-tool, e.g. DotTrace. That enables you far better insight into your application and where time is wasted. In particular you gain insight in if your problems are even caused by what you think they are. As it is there´s no way for us to identify why your code may be slow, as we have no clue on what it actually does. Thus it´s hard to give any better solution.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. I checked profiler and i found that time wastes happens in coroutines. So, I started searching for a way to change my IEnumerator's to void but without losing the waiting feature of IEnumerator. Thanks again. Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace

```
while (_Something != null) { yield return null; }
```

with

`yield return new waituntill(_Something == null)`

PS: it would be better if you paste the whole code instead of a general scenario.

Comment: Hello, thanks so much for your fast reply and your tip. The code is too long and confusing. So, I didnt want to share it. But the general concept of my code is like that. I'm trying to find a way to use void methods instead of IEnumerator.

Comment: Why don't you use Actions/Delegates instead of forcing your processor to wait for a certain task?